# Hide all but first children per parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide all the child elements(`.push_down`) of each `.parent` except the first one (`.push_down[0]`) and I have tried with the following code but this is not the right way as it's not working. If anyone knows the right way please answer.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var len = $('.parent').length;
  for(let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var blocks = $('.parent').[i].$('.push_down');
    var block_len = $('.parent').[i].$('.push_down').length;
    for(let j = 1; j < block_len; j++) {
      $('.parent').[i].$('.push_down')[j].addClass('hidden');
    }
  } 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .block{
        height: 200px;
        background: lavender;
        padding: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #000;
    }
    .push_down {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body> 
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">         

            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-sm-8">
                <div class="parent">
                    <div class="panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading push_down">
                            <div class="block">
                                BLOCK A
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="panel-heading push_down">
                            <div class="block">
                                BLOCK B
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="panel-heading push_down">
                            <div class="block">
                                Here
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="panel-heading push_down">
                            <div class="block">
                                Where
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="panel-heading push_down">
                            <div class="block">
                                Dark
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="panel-heading push_down">
                            <div class="block">
                                BLOCK B
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>  
                </div>

                <div class="parent">
                    <div class="panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading push_down">
                            <div class="block">
                                BLOCK AA
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="panel-heading push_down">
                            <div class="block">
                                BLOCK BB
                            </div>
                        </div>              
                    </div>  
                </div>  
            </div>




        </div>  
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: $(".push_down").addClass("hidden"); $(".push_down").first().removeClass("hidden");   or $(".parent:first-child").removeClass("hidden");

Comment: it will hide all the blocks

Comment: I want a single block shown

Comment: sorry i was editing my answer

Comment: or $(".parent").find(".push_down:first").addClass("hidden");  i sended you 3 options to show one block only afterthe all hiddens class

Comment: I want to show a single block of each parent class

Comment: try last option then,
 $(".push_down").addClass("hidden");
$(".parent").find(".push_down:first").addClass("hidden");

Comment: It's ok! take ur time

Comment: it works now or ?

Comment: no not working, hiding all the divs

Comment: try this, first-child no first, $(".push_down").addClass("hidden"); $(".parent").find(".push_down:first-child").addClass("hidden"); check this example, it works https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_sel_firstchild_first

Comment: Hi there, I've come up with a working solution and have included it in a code snippet below for testing. Please check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below code. I'm finding each `.parent` class then finding the `.push_down` classes using the `:gt()` selector which will select all the elements higher than the given value, in this case `0`. Find the working solution in the below code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.parent').find('.push_down:gt(0)').hide();
});
```

```css
.block {
  height: 200px;
  background: lavender;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000;
}

.push_down {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-sm-8">
        <div class="parent">
          <div class="panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading push_down">
              <div class="block">
                BLOCK A
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-heading push_down">
              <div class="block">
                BLOCK B
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-heading push_down">
              <div class="block">
                Here
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-heading push_down">
              <div class="block">
                Where
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-heading push_down">
              <div class="block">
                Dark
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-heading push_down">
              <div class="block">
                BLOCK B
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="parent">
          <div class="panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading push_down">
              <div class="block">
                BLOCK AA
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-heading push_down">
              <div class="block">
                BLOCK BB
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @AbhayjeetSingh Glad I could help.. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  $('.parent').find('.push_down:not(:first)').hide();
```

or try this

```
$('.parent').each(function(){
      $(this).find('.push_down:not(:first)').hide();
});
```